# Fortran write statement: what is this "9999" doing?

Tags: fortran

I can't figure out what in the world this "9999" is doing in front of the e20.8, in the label of this fortran write statement.

Is does not refer to any other line in the code. In other words, there isn't a line labeled 9999 to which it refers, elsewhere in the program.

```
write(11,'(9999e20.8)') (9999.0, i=1,2*(numant+numunique))
```

I'm boggled - I haven't found the answer from google web searches, although I think I get the general picture about write statement syntax and formatting.

Is this enough info provided to make sense?

Answer (score 3):

It's a repetition count; the general format for a format code is (count)(type)(format), eg as described in [this tutorial here](http://math.scu.edu/~dsmolars/ma169/notesfortran.html#format).

Unlike C-based languages, unused formatting codes are simply ignored, so this line essentially says "write out as many real numbers in scientific format (with 8 digits after the decimal) as there are in the following output list".   (If you don't like doing it this way, with a hardcoded "big enough" number, you'd have to programatically generate the format string to have the "right" repetition code.

The output list is an [implied-do loop](http://jblevins.org/log/array-write), which generates the number 9999.0 `2*(numant+numuniqe)` times.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonathan.  I think I understand your reply, but now I don't understand the point of having the repetition count.  Since the output already is looped by the i index "(9999.0, i=1,2*(numant+numunique)", why do they need to say repeat this format, e20.8, nine thousand nine hundred and ninety-nine times?  You already answered, so if you don't have time for this follow up, still, many thanks. - Shana

Comment: You need one format code per output item, so there needs to be at least `2*(numant+numunique)` of those `e20.8`s.  But that value isn't known at compile time, so the line above makes 9999 of them and trusts that'll be enough.  The alternative is to generate the format string at run time, which actually isn't that hard.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Thank you so much. I will look into your suggested alternative. Many thanks & good wishes.