# Legacy Fortran FORMAT Edit Descriptor Syntax - Number Before Type?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

In a snippet of legacy FORTRAN code (actual compiler unknown, suspect it was circa FORTRAN-77), I found a statement like this:

```
100 FORMAT(5I7.2)
```

Which I interpret to mean:

- Integer
- Width 7 characters, of which
- 2 characters are decimals (e.g., '12345.67')

What I can't find is an explanation of the leading '5'. I assume it means something to the effect of "repeating group," say--five groups of seven integers...etc.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I'm slightly reluctant to call this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13162910, but that's certainly relevant.  You're interpretation of `I7.2` isn't quite right, also: it implies possible leading zeros.

Comment: not a dup, but the answer is readily found in any fortran text/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran 2008 defines the `I` edit descriptor in Section 10.7.2.2.  The relevant paragraphs to your question are (excerpts):

> 1 The Iw and Iw .m edit descriptors indicate that the field to be edited occupies w positions, except when w is zero.
>   When w is zero, the processor selects the field width. On input, w shall not be zero. The specified input/output
>   list item shall be of type integer.
>
> 5 The output field for the Iw .m edit descriptor is the same as for the Iw edit descriptor, except that the digit-string
>   consists of at least m digits. If necessary, sufficient leading zeros are included to achieve the minimum of m digits.

This means that `I7.2` will be 7 digits wide and at least two digits will always be displayed, 0-padded.

The preceding `5` in the edit descriptor is a *repeat specification* (Fortran 2008 10.3.1 paragraph 1) and is a repeat count of the following edit descriptor.

Put together, `5I7.2` will output 5 integers, each 7 digits wide displaying a minimum of 2 digits being zero padded to two digits if necessary.